# Is it possible to configure specific per profile sample rate and format in Pulseaudio/ALSA?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a sound card/dac/amp (Sennheiser GSX1000) that has two very different profiles: one of them is a 7.1 surround sound that works if and only if the sample format is 16 bits/48khz lower; while the other one, 2.0 HD audio, only works if the config is at least 24 bit/96000khz.

As each one of the configurations invalidate the other one, I created a mapping and profile for each of these two sound profiles in a `.conf` file in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/`, and the way I switch **profiles** now is by editing the `default-sample-rate` and `default-sample-format` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and then reloading pulseaudio (**pulseaudio -k**), which is kinda bothering.

I would like to know if is there a way to set specific sample-rate and format for each profile instead of a whole sound card in some config file, so the switch is smoother and more natural.

I have thought of other solutions like creating a daemon that subscribes to pulseaudio events and then detect the profile change, check the selected profile, go change the files and restart the pulseaudio daemon, but I would leave that as the last option.